# Social sharing of dynamic url with hashtags

Tags: javascript, facebook, metadata, share, hashtag

I'm building a client side plugin that functions very similar to an image/article gallery within a 3rd party application.

When an article/image is being clicked at the gallery, the page's url hashtags is being modified so that each image/article will have an absolute url.

While trying to add a Facebook share/like buttons for each one of the images I'm facing the following problem - Facebook (or Twitter) will scrape the original page and get the parent page meta data, but not the actual content of the image/article which is being shared/liked.

As far as I'm aware, there is no dynamic way via the API to tell FB what content to place on the feed. However, it is crucial for this project that the feed will display the image and some specific meta data that is related to this image/article.

I also believe that FB will not run the Javascript so even if I'd dynamically replace the main page's meta tags, the scraped info will still be the original info.

The only solution seems to be server side but of course that would be outside the scope of this project and I will have no way of determining which server side language the clients will be using.

Is there a client-side-only way of achieving this?

If not - is there a way to have the landing page (the page that people jump to when clicking on the FB post) different than the meta tag url (so I could have this scrapped from a different url than the client's url)?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you share to Facebook needs to return the Open Graph meta tags to Facebook's crawler when Facebook accesses that URL ( more info about the crawler and best practices here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices )

If your URLs are such that there's client side logic or redirects incompatible with the crawler, that's fine in theory, but you'd need to special case your code to return consistent markup to the crawler at that URL withour redirecting, and provide the other / existing to other browsers (but that's prone to error and would only fix it for FB's crawler and not other services)

Ideally, the URls you share should show the content shared (i.e. be a permalink to that image or article), and you link back to category or other functionality from that page, or load the 'parent' content (not sure of your exact use case) dynamically later